# Saito-Wright definition of Rickart C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

A C*-algebra is *Rickart* if for each  $x\in  A$ there is a projection $p\in A$ so that
$R(x)=pA$. 
Here the right-annihilator $R(S)$ of $S\subset A$ is defined
as $$R(S)=\{a\in A\mid xa=0\, \forall x\in S\}$$ and $R(x)\equiv R(\{x\})$.

In:

> Kazuyuki Saito and J. D. Maitland Wright. [$C^∗$-algebras which are Grothendieck
>   spaces](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02871928). *Rend. Circ. Mat. Palermo* (2), 52(1):141–144, 2003.

an alternative definition is studied:
define a C*-algebra to be *Rickart* if each maximal Abelian *-subalgebra of $A$ is Rickart (or, equivalently, monotone $\sigma$-complete).
Equivalently, one may require that every Abelian *-subalgebra is contained in an
Abelian Rickart C*-algebra.

This definition is more general and seems to be sufficient for many applications.

> Is this definition in fact equivalent to the original one?

This question recently came up in our investigations in the foundations of quantum theory:

[Bohrification of operator algebras and quantum logic](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2275)

Comment: Based on the remarks in your paper, this may deserve the "open-problem" tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are equivalent. See [*On Defining AW**-*algebras and Rickart C**-*algebras* by K. Saitô, and J.D.M. Wright](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02434) (arXiv:1501.02434)

Comment: Oh dear, why down-vote?

Comment: Welcome to MO, and thanks for filling this gap in the literature!